How to insert missing rows into a table based upon a group by?
I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a table and insert missing rows with '0' or null scores based upon the name. For example, I have a table with these values:



Stage
ID
Name
Score




stage 1
234
name1
10


Stage 2
234
name1
10


Stage 3
234
name1
10


Stage 4
234
name1
20


Stage 6
234
name1
5


Stage 7
234
name1
10


Stage 1
200
name2
20


Stage 3
200
name2
20


Stage 4
200
name2
20


Stage 5
200
name2
20


Stage 6
200
name2
20


Stage 7
200
name2
20


Stage 1
101
name3
10


Stage 2
101
name3
10


Stage 3
101
name3
10


Stage 4
101
name3
10


Stage 5
101
name3
10


Stage 6
101
name3
10


Stage 7
101
name3
10


Stage 3
300
name4
20



I want to insert missing rows with '0' as a score to have a table that looks like this:



Stage
ID
Name
Score




stage 1
234
name1
10


Stage 2
234
name1
10


Stage 3
234
name1
10


Stage 4
234
name1
20


Stage 5
234
name1
0


Stage 6
234
name1
5


Stage 7
234
name1
10


Stage 1
200
name2
20


Stage 2
200
name2
0


Stage 3
200
name2
20


Stage 4
200
name2
20


Stage 5
200
name2
20


Stage 6
200
name2
20


Stage 7
200
name2
20


Stage 1
101
name3
10


Stage 2
101
name3
10


Stage 3
101
name3
10


Stage 4
101
name3
10


Stage 5
101
name3
10


Stage 6
101
name3
10


Stage 7
101
name3
10


Stage 1
300
name4
0


Stage 2
300
name4
0


Stage 3
300
name4
10


Stage 4
300
name4
0


Stage 5
300
name4
0


Stage 6
300
name4
0


Stage 7
300
name4
0




Well that sucks, the formatting of the tables example is completely unreadable. Not sure how to edit the question to make it more readable.

You haven't used any (table) markdown so there is no formatting.

As a separate note, looping is the last thing you should be doing in SQL; it is a set based language so you should be using set based solutions.

You can do an insert-select, like this one:
INSERT INT stages([Stage ID], [Name], [Score])
SELECT t.[Stage ID], t.[Name], t.[Score]
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS [Stage ID], 'a' AS [Name], 0 AS [Score]
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'b', 0
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 'c', 0
    UNION
    SELECT 4, 'd', 0
) t
LEFT JOIN stages
ON t.[Stage ID] = stages.[Stage ID]
WHERE stages.[Stage ID] IS NULL
GROUP BY t.[Stage ID]

Explanation:

we select each record we want to insert
we union them into a single relation
we name the result as t
we left join t with stages, to see whether a record exists in the stages table that matches the stage id of the current record in t
we exclude the records where a match was found, as we only want to insert unmatched records
and then we execute the insert on the result we thusly found


Thanks, how would I do this grouped by badge?

@jarheadtx can you elaborate? Which table is Badge a field of?

Sorry, I meant [Stage ID] in the example. How would I do this grouped by [Stage ID]?

@jarheadtx you just append GROUP BY t.[Stage ID]. I have edited my answer and added that line.
